# Crossword puzzle clue Y's guys?

Tags: crosswords, crossword-clues

In the [New York Times Tuesday October 14, 2008 crossword puzzle](https://www.xwordinfo.com/Crossword?date=10/14/2008), 18 across, 4 letters, is "Y's guys?" and the answer is:

> ELIS

It must be fairly obvious but I can't figure out what this means. The question mark indicates it's a pun or something… Is it a name (if so, what's the connection to Y)? Is it an acronym (haven't found a relevant one)?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Eli" is slang for a person who went to Yale, as mentioned in [this Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Yale-called-the-Elis). (This is because [Elihu Yale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elihu_Yale) is the eponym of Yale University.)

Presumably Yale is also just called "Y", then (though I can't find any source for that with a bit of cursory research). So "Y's guys" are "those from Yale", which are Elis.